# Object initialization sequence in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, init

The Cocoa framework has a convention to always call `self = [super init]` in the `init` method of an inherited class, because `[super init]` may return a new instance.

What will happen if I do this?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject /* or any other class */ {
    int ivar_;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (id)init {
    ivar_ = 12345;

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSLog(@"ivar_'s value is %d", ivar_);
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In the case when `[super init]` returns a new instance, what will I see in the console? `ivar_'s value is 0`?

I can't think of a way to check this myself, because I don't know which class may return a new instance from its `init` method. Also, can't seem to find explicit clarification for this scenario in the docs.

Could anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: I misunderstood your question. So deleted my answer. It is technically possible for an init to return the instance of different class. I thought you were asking about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, when you send `+alloc` to a class it returns a zeroed out instance of that class. It is already initialised in the sense that: a) it is a proper instance of that class, and b) all instance variables are zeroed out (numeric types are 0, C pointers are NULL, objects are nil, etc). However, no extra initialisation behaviour has been applied to the newly created instance — that’s the job of initialisers, `-init` being the most common of them. In particular, if your class inherits from `NSObject` then `[super init]` doesn’t touch the newly created instance. So, in the code you’ve posted in your question,

1. (outside the class) `+alloc` is sent to `MyClass`, which returns a zeroed out instance. In particular, `ivar_` is 0
2. (outside the class) `-init` is sent to the newly created instance
3. `ivar_ == 12345` because of the assignment in `-init`, which could be rewritten as `self->ivar_ = 12345`. At this moment, `self` points to the instance returned by `+alloc`
4. `[super init]` is sent, `ivar_` isn’t touched since its superclass (`NSObject`) doesn’t know about it, and the return value is assigned to `self`. In fact, the return value is already `self` so nothing’s changed
5. Since `self` is different from `nil`, `NSLog()` is called
6. `-init` returns `self`

Now let’s consider that `[super init]` returns an instance that’s different from the one returned by `+alloc`:

1. (outside the class) `+alloc` is sent to `MyClass`, which returns a zeroed out instance. In particular, `ivar_` is 0
2. (outside the class) `-init` is sent to the newly created instance
3. `ivar_ == 12345` because of the assignment in `-init`, which could be rewritten as `self->ivar_ = 12345`. At this moment, `self` points to the instance returned by `+alloc`
4. `[super init]` is sent *and it decides to release the current instance and return a different one*. The return value is assigned to `self` so, from the current perspective, `-init` is now working on a different instance. The old instance was deallocated, hence that change to `ivar_` is lost. *`ivar_` contains whatever `[super init]` decides it should contain*
5. Since `self` is different from `nil`, `NSLog()` is called
6. `-init` returns `self`, which is not the same instance created by `+alloc`

You can test this with the following code. Be warned that it’s just a quick example to illustrate my answer and it should not be used in production code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MySuperClass : NSObject
@end

@interface MyClass : MySuperClass
{
  @public
  int ivar_;
}
@end

@implementation MySuperClass

static MyClass *defaultInstance;

- (id)init
{
  if ([self isMemberOfClass:[MyClass class]] && defaultInstance != nil)
  {
    [self release];
    return defaultInstance;
  }

  return [super init];
}
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (id)init
{
  ivar_ = 12345;

  if ((self = [super init]))
    NSLog(@"ivar_'s value is %d", ivar_);

  return self;
}
@end

int main()
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

  defaultInstance = nil;
  defaultInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"%d", defaultInstance->ivar_); // outputs 12345

  defaultInstance->ivar_ = 98765;
  NSLog(@"%d", defaultInstance->ivar_); // outputs 98765

  MyClass *someInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"%d", someInstance->ivar_); // outputs 98765

  if (someInstance == defaultInstance)
    NSLog(@"They're the same!");

  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
ivar_'s value is 12345
12345
98765
ivar_'s value is 98765
98765
They're the same!
```

Comment: I see your point. Now that I'm thinking of it, I realize that there is no way for `[super init]` to return a newly created instance without falling into infinite recursion. Please tell me if I'm wrong. Anyway, the answer to the posed question is clear to me now: `self = [super init]` has to be the first line of any init method, even though it is not stated explicitly in the docs. Thanks for your sample code.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot simply allocate a new instance because that would yield infinite recursion alright. And yup, `self = [super init]` (or variations of `-init`) should be the first line of any _normal_ initialiser because there’s no guarantee that `[super init]` returns the same instance. If it did, there’d be no point in assigning the return value of `[super init]` to `self`.